# asp.net, javascript, Unable to get value of the property getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, asp.net, getelementbyid

Im using asp.net with c# and javascript.
I have a master page and many aspx pages that use it.
On the master page, I have an unordered list which is actually a menu.

The unordered list has ID and `runat ="server"`. The problem is when I put `"runat ="server""` on the unordered list. I get the error: `"Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'getElementsByTagName': object is null or undefined."` And it points to a script.js which is used for the functionality of the menu. specifically at a line which is:........

```
a=c; var w=document.getElementById(p), s=w.getElementsByTagName('ul'), l=s.length, i=0;
```

On the master page, on the head, the script is called like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>
```

Full code of script.js:

```
var menu=function(){
    var t=15,z=50,s=6,a;
    function dd(n){this.n=n; this.h=[]; this.c=[]}
    dd.prototype.init=function(p,c){
        a=c; var w=document.getElementById(p), s=w.getElementsByTagName('ul'), l=s.length, i=0;
        for(i;i<l;i++){
            var h=s[i].parentNode; this.h[i]=h; this.c[i]=s[i];
            h.onmouseover=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+',true)');
            h.onmouseout=new Function(this.n+'.st('+i+')');
        }
    }
    dd.prototype.st=function(x,f){
        var c=this.c[x], h=this.h[x], p=h.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
        clearInterval(c.t); c.style.overflow='hidden';
        if(f){
            p.className+=' '+a;
            if(!c.mh){c.style.display='block'; c.style.height=''; c.mh=c.offsetHeight; c.style.height=0}
            if(c.mh==c.offsetHeight){c.style.overflow='visible'}
            else{c.style.zIndex=z; z++; c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,1)},t)}
        }else{p.className=p.className.replace(a,''); c.t=setInterval(function(){sl(c,-1)},t)}
    }
    function sl(c,f){
        var h=c.offsetHeight;
        if((h<=0&&f!=1)||(h>=c.mh&&f==1)){
            if(f==1){c.style.filter=''; c.style.opacity=1; c.style.overflow='visible'}
            clearInterval(c.t); return
        }
        var d=(f==1)?Math.ceil((c.mh-h)/s):Math.ceil(h/s), o=h/c.mh;
        c.style.opacity=o; c.style.filter='alpha(opacity='+(o*100)+')';
        c.style.height=h+(d*f)+'px'
    }
    return{dd:dd}
}();
```

The unordered list menu is declared inside the form1:

This is the List menu code:.

```
<ul class="menu" id="menu" runat ="server"> 
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="menulink">Mant</a> 
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="Mant.aspx">Table</a></li> 
    </ul> 
  </li> 
</ul>
```

Outside the form1 , this is declared:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var menu = new menu.dd("menu");
menu.init("menu", "menuhover");
</script>
```

All the code is declared on the master page, except from the script.js.

How can I solve this?

Thanks...

Post edited.

Comment: You need to include more context, specifically where p is declared and/or assigned. This error is most likely from document.getElementById(p) failing.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't provided enough code for a concrete answer, but my hunch is as follows...

By default ASP.Net changes the ID of elements that contain `runat="server"` to ensure that all ID's are unique. You have two choices:

1. Ask ASP.Net for the client ID in your JS:

   `var clientID = "<%= txtUsername.ClientID %>";`
2. Take a look at the [`ClientIDMode` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx). Setting it to `Static`, at least for the element in question should fix the issue.

This error could also be the result of executing the JS before the page has fully rendered. Again, you haven't provided enough code for us to make this determination.

Comment: @pyram, did you try one of the ID fixes I suggested? Can you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that replicates the issue?

Comment: You can't - can you replicate the issue outside of the master page?

Answer (score 0):

It is `null` because JavaScript executed before the element was created.  You can ADD to onload.
http://jsfiddle.net/vwvzN/

James Hill seems to have the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var menu = new menu.dd(<%= menu.ClientID %>);
menu.init(<%= menu.ClientID %>, "menuhover");
</script>
```